# Make a point about something

Tags: meaning

How can I understand the following [example](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english-russian/point_1) (the very first):

> Could I ***make a point*** about noise levels?

Is make a point an idiomatic expression or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to understand it is to read this *make* as "express" and this *point* as "idea/opinion".

> *Could I **make a point** about noise levels?*
>   (= Could I express my idea/opinion about noise levels?)

---

Is *make a point* idiomatic? Yes.

Is *make a point* an idiom? Probably not. I'd call it a [collocation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collocation) (sense 1.1).

English has a handful of basic words (e.g. *make, do, get*) that can have a wide range of meanings, depending on context. Learning their collocates is useful. Macmillan lists a few of collocates of **[point](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/point_1)**:

> Verbs frequently used with **point** as the object
>   ▪ illustrate, labor, make, prove, raise